# How to handle the execution of a set of scripts in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sometimes I have to apply this kind of sql script that has in another folder more scripts:

```
PROMPT "--------------------------------------"
PROMPT "        APLICANDO Edward"
PROMPT "--------------------------------------" 

@./Packages/Edward.sql
@./Packages/Edward2.sql
.
.
.

prompt "------------------------------------------------------"
prompt " FIN DE APLICA Edward"
prompt "------------------------------------------------------"
```

Usually I had to put that .zip file on the server and execute it in sqlplus, but I don't know if could execute them in SQLDeveloper (in a windows environment). Is there some way to do it in that tool?

Comment: SQL Developer supports calling external scripts using the `@file_name.sql` syntax.  Have you tried running your script in SQL Developer?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  I'd guess that the files aren't where SQL Developer is set to look for them given the relative path but I don't know what you're trying.

Comment: I didnt try to execute this before, because i dont have where to test it. The scripts have commits on it and the environments are for production purposes. I know that SQLDev deals with scripts but I dunno if can handle the secuential execution of scripts given a master script and a folder full of them.

Comment: _"The scripts have commits on it and the environments are for production purposes"_   Don't you have some kind of test environment? How do you test other things before going into production?

Comment: Sure there is some environments to deal with that, but I merely a junior and not a Dev so I dont have how to replicate this in a Test Oracle database, only asked if someone have tried this before.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not running the scripts using SQL Developer in production, I would not recommend using SQL Developer to test the scripts. You always want your testing to be as close as possible to production.

You had said that SQLPlus will be used run the scripts in production, so I would recommend installing the same version of SQLPlus on your machine to test out the scripts. Running scripts from SQL Developer runs them using [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html) so the behavior could be slightly different than SQLPlus. Oracle says SQLcl it is 99% compatible with SQLPlus, but without knowing what is in your scripts and what version of SQLPlus/SQLcl/SQL Developer you are using, we can not know for sure.

If you are determined on running your scripts from SQL Developer, in a SQL Worksheet, you just need to change directories to where your scripts live, then execute them just like you would from the command line. If you are on an older version of SQL Developer (pre-SQLcl) this may not work so you will need to upgrade your version of SQL Developer.

[image: SQL Worksheet screenshot]